# How can I deploy OSQA to heroku

Tags: django, heroku, osqa

I have a problem when I deploy OSQA to heroku.

Firstly, I clone OSQA source code from https://github.com/dzone/osqa

And I do some steps like the tutorial in https://github.com/joshfinnie/OSQA-Heroku

Finally, when I access to my website, I get the error message such as

ImproperlyConfigured at /
The included urlconf urls doesn't have any patterns in it
And the stack trace is as follow

/app/forum/views/readers.py in index
    paginator_context.base_path = reverse('questions')
I don't know what wrong I config. So, I hope anyone can help me resolve my problem.
The link of heroku is http://where-we-go.herokuapp.com/

Thank you so much.

Comment: seems http://osqa-heroku.herokuapp.com/ also not working..  Anyway what about the foreman start result ?

Comment: I can deploy in local successfully. But I don't know why there is a bug when I deploy to heroku. One more thing, I run OSQA in windows for local setup so I don't use foreman. Btw, the link of heroku is http://where-we-go.herokuapp.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the root cause. I downgrade the version of Markdown to 2.4.1 and OSQA works fine