# TypeError 'NoneType' object is not iterable OSQA

Tags: django, osqa

i've configured well the OSQA Django but how to correct this issue when i  try this url :

```
http://localhost/questions/ask/
```

in debog mod :

```
TypeError at /questions/ask/
'NoneType' object is not iterable
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost/questions/ask/
Django Version: 1.6
Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value:    
'NoneType' object is not iterable
Exception Location: /home/mm/osqa/osqa-server/forum/markdownext/mdx_settingsparser.py in __init__, line 13 :

Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python
Python Version: 2.7.6
Python Path:    
['/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/South-1.0-py2.7.egg',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django_debug_toolbar-1.2.1-py2.7.egg',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlparse-0.1.12-py2.7.egg',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Markdown-2.5-py2.7.egg',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/html5lib-1.0b3-py2.7.egg',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/python_openid-2.2.5-py2.7.egg',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.6-py2.7.egg',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/elementtree-1.2.7_20070827_preview-py2.7.egg',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ipython-2.2.0-py2.7.egg',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PILcompat',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gst-0.10',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0',
 '/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntu-sso-client',
 '/home/marwen/osqa',
 '/home/marwen/osqa/osqa-server',
 '/home/marwen/osqa/osqa-server/forum/markdownext']
Server time:    Fri, 26 Sep 2014 11:17:48 -0400
```

edit with code line 13 :

```
         for key, value in configs:
            self.config[key] = value
```

Comment: show the relevant code from `/home/mm/osqa/osqa-server/forum/markdownext/mdx_settingsparser.py in __init__, line 13`

Comment: when i remove the portion on code on line 13 it working well ! here is the code :    for key, value in configs:
            self.config[key] = value

Comment: Just the stacktrace and saying "not working" is not helpful. You will have to show the code if you want to be helped

Comment: This means that either configs is `None`. Do you mean to say `self.configs` instead of `configs` ?

Comment: no its configs from the init constructor

Comment: So, that is being evaluated as `None` - You might want to initialize it to `{}` instead of None if no config attributes are present.

Comment: how to write it with python

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's hard to tell with no stack trace of the error, but I think I've had a similar problem with OSQA recently. The problem was a breaking change in v2.5 of the Markdown plugin. If you revert your installation to use v2.4.1 it might resolve this error.

Comment: @Mirlo, if you don't downgrade the version of Markdown to 2.4.1, you will get the error in the future. Please see my question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25859451/how-can-i-deploy-osqa-to-heroku